# Drop down List is moving Up when searching

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

My Angular application using ngx-intl-tel-input library when i search country on country list dropdown moving to top .I want to fix  postion of dropdown menu when searching on that.

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-5u5c1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
    <div style="margin: 50px">
  <br>

  <form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
    <div class="mb-2">
      <ngx-intl-tel-input 
        [cssClass]="'custom'" 
        [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
        [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" 
        [enablePlaceholder]="true" 
        [searchCountryFlag]="true"
        [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
        [selectFirstCountry]="false" 
        [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.India"
        [maxLength]="15" 
        [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name" 
        [phoneValidation]="true" 
        [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode"
        name="phone" formControlName="phone">
      </ngx-intl-tel-input>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
      <button (click)="f.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br>

</div>
```

GIF:[Issue gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSseQ.gif)

Comment: please add some of your relevant code :) (in my computer the position of demo is in the bottom)

Comment: Hi , staclblitz- link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-5u5c1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: issue screen shot https://ibb.co/sgqxGTX

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-8 checkout this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `ngx-intl-tel-input` package to 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css code as below to give the box a fixed position(use `!important` to prevent override)

```
:host ngx-intl-tel-input  ::ng-deep .country-dropdown{
    left: 0px!important;
    right: auto!important;
    top: 100%!important;
    transform: translateY(0px)!important;
    bottom: auto!important;
}
```

[SEE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-a4crnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick response but the issue is not solved. Scrolling problem GIF https://imgur.com/SgsxBpo

Comment: Can you attach the img/gif to your question (I can not open it due security in my computer )

Answer (score 0):

Your html page contains overflow style that's why it scroll up when type specific country, so you just need to unset it.